# Context-aware Locator

Tags: manipulate, image-processing, locator

I'm trying to use a `Locator` for some image processing tasks. Unfortunately, the images we're using have a high dynamic range of low-frequency black and white features. I've made a custom `Appearance` for the `Locator` with some concentric circles that works pretty well, but am wondering about using other compositing operations instead, like, Xor.

The current implementation of `Locator` seems to composite with a simple Over operator. Meaning that the 'cross hairs' disappear on black patches.

Has anyone successfully created a more dynamic locator appearance or have some thoughts about how one might do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you can change the compositing operator but you can dynamically change the appearance. A simple example:

```
im = LinearGradientImage[];

DynamicModule[{pt = {10, 10}},
 LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt], im, Appearance -> Graphics[{
     Dynamic @ GrayLevel[1 - PixelValue[im, pt]], Disk[]}, ImageSize -> 20]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Ah! I hadn't thought of using `PixelValue[]`- beautifully simple, thanks mate!